# I can access the querystring variable on a GET request, but not a POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I try and access a webpage that has a filter that checks for authentication, it redirects to the login page when I am surfing anonymous.  So the URL may look like:

```
www.example.com/user/login?ReturnUrl=/user/settings
```

My Login action has 2 methods, when for GET and one for POST request types.

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")
public ActionResult Login()
{
}
[AcceptVerbs("POST")
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection f)
{
}
```

The following code is in both the GET and POST login action:

```
 string redirectUrl = "";

 if(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
 {
  redirectUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
 }
```

When in debug mode, the variable is initialized properly in the GET action, but in the POST action it just skips the call, which means it is NULL.

Why is this?  The ReturnUrl is still visible in the url?

Comment: I cannot recreate this behavior. Your form action url *does* include the return url, right?

Comment: no it doesn't, the form is posting to /user/login

Comment: Well then there's your problem! You'd need it to post to the full url including querystring, eg. <form action="/user/login?ReturnUrl=/user/settings" method="post">

Comment: Why not just change your signature for the POST to:

    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection f, string ReturnUrl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing query string parameters with a POST is technically not RFC-compliant, you're supposed to do one or the other, but not both.  (Having said that I've not come across a browser / web-server that doesn't allow this).

If you wanted to do it "properly" you'd have the ReturnUrl as a hidden input field on the form and retrieve it along with the other form variables on the server.

Comment: Would you be able to site that RFC, as I understand it a query is just further data to be passed to a resource.

Answer (score 0):

in case of POST request, check `Request.Form["returnUrl"]` property

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here at the HttpContext.Request object.

There is lots of useful information returned available in either a GET or POST request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_members.aspx